# How to plot negative values on x-axis from min to max (from -1 to 0)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I got a plot where on x-axis there are negative values from -0.15 to -1, but I need them from -1 to 0.

I plotted values (both positive and negative) by `geom_bar` in `ggplot` function. I got a plot where on x-axis there are negative values from -0.15 to -1, but I need them from -1 to 0.

Could you help how to fix it?

data frame looks like:

```
 id    value33333
<dbl> <chr>     
  1      -0.6      
  2      -0.8      
  3      -1        
  4      -0.2      
  5      -1        
  6       0.4       
  7      -1        
  8      -1        
  9      -0.6      
 10       0.1       
 11      -0.6      
 12      -1        
 13       0.1       
 14       0.15      
 15       0.5       
 16       0.4       
 17      -0.95     
 18       0.5       
 19      -0.6      
 20       0.05
```

I need to plot value33333 on x-axis and percent on y axis.

Thanks a lot!

```
ggplot(data = value33333) + geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = value33333, y = ..prop.., group = 1), stat = "count") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) + theme_bw()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `xlim(-1.1,0)` (`-1.1` to include the last bar) works without errors.

```
head(value33333)
  interviewer internalID value
1      Nuriya          3  -0.6
2      Nuriya          5  -0.8
3      Nuriya          7  -1.0
4      Nuriya          9  -0.2
5      Nuriya         11  -1.0
6      Nuriya         13   0.4


ggplot(data = value33333) + 
geom_bar(aes(x = value, y = ..prop.., group = 1), stat = "count") + 
scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) + theme_bw() + 
xlim(-1.1,0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it gives an Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Comment: what about `scale_x_discrete(limits = c(-1, 0))`? It would be worth to edit your original question and add a dummy DF to play with. Also check `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22992375/xlim-not-working-for-discrete-values-ggplot2`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems like I fixed it, I used as.nimeric for x variable in the code above: ggplot(data = value33333) + geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = as.numeric(value33333), y = ..prop.., group = 1), stat = "count") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) + scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-1,1)) + theme_bw()